# Pyomo: Error during generation of .nl-file for solver interface

Tags: pyomo

I am using a concrete model to set up several optimization problems. 
However, in some cases, there occurs an error when solving the pyomo model with Gurobi_AMPL via the SolverFactory `(opt = SolverFactory('gurobi_ampl',solver_io='nl'))`.

In this case, python returns the following error code in combination with a MemoryError:

```
File "C:\win32app\Winpython\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py, line 599, in solve
    self._presolve(*args,**kwds)
File "C:\win32app\Winpython\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\ASL.py", line 189, in _presolve
    SystemCallSolver._presolve(self, *args, **kwds)
File "C:\win32app\Winpython\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py", line 196, in _pyresolve
    OptSolver._presolve(self, *args, **kwds)
File "C:\win32app\Winpython\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 699, in _presolve
    **kwds)
File "C:\win32app\Winpython\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 770, in _convert_problem
    **kwds)
File "C:\win32app\Winpython\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\convert.py", line 110, in convert_problem
    problem_files, symbol_map = converter.apply(*tmp, **tmpkw)
File "C:\win32app\Winpython\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\converter\model.py", line 192, in apply
    io_options=io_options)
File "C:\win32app\Winpython\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py", line 1681, in write
    io_options)
File "C:\win32app\Winpython\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyomo\repn\plugins\ampl\ampl_.py", line 392, in __call__
    include_all_variable_bounds=include_all_variable_bounds)
File "C:\win32app\Winpython\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyomo\repn\plugins\ampl\ampl_.py", line 1177, in _print_model_NL
    for column_id,var_ID in enumerate(full_var_list)])
File "C:\win32app\Winpython\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\kernel\symbol_map.py", line 68, in addSymbols
    self.bySymbol.update((symb_, weakref_ref(obj_)) for obj_,symb_ in tuples)
MemoryError
```

The error is probably not really a MemoryError since I do not get any excessive peak in the memory usage. 
But, it seems to me that the generation of the .nl-file causes the error.

Nevertheless, the separate generation of the .nl-file using model.write('model.nl'), generates the .nl-file without error.

Is this a familiar problem? 
Can such an error be caused by setting up the model with improper parameter values?

Comment: How large is your model?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.
The model has about 300000 variables and 230000 constraints.